# What is the filtration described?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, pricing, derivatives, risk-neutral-measure, forward

What is the filtration $(\mathfrak{F}_t)$ encircled below?

Is it $(\mathfrak{F}_t) = (\sigma(W_t)) = (\sigma(\tilde{W_t})), t \in [0,T]$?

Or is it $(\mathfrak{F}_t) = (\sigma(\hat{W_t})), t \in [0,T]$?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

The [reference](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic_finance.pdf) (p. 271, 275, 336) and suggests that it is in fact the $(\sigma(W_t)) = (\sigma(\tilde{W_t}))$, but I am not really sure I am reading this right.

If so, does that mean there are 2 probability measures being considered in the martingale? Risk neutral measure for filtration and Forward measure for probability measure>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the former. Martingales are defined by filtration and probability space*. The probability space* for the filtration need not be the same as the probability space* for the martingale.

[I think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_%28probability_theory%29#General_definition)?

That's what my prof said (iirc).

*specifically the probability measure

Comment: Generally, you can add your answer to your question or comments, unless a significant solution that is really worth for standalone.