# Is $\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}$ martingale?

Tags: martingale, zero-coupon

Assume $r_t$ follow the CIR process and $P(t,T)=E[exp(-\int_{t}^{T}r_s ds)|F_t]$.I am going to show $\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}$ ($S<T$) is an $F_t$-martingale under Forward Measure but So confused!
Do I need to solve C.I.R process?
Should I use the definition of martingale?
please guide me!
so thanks.

Comment: Maybe see [reference](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic_finance.pdf) (p. 271, 275, 336 or something else) in my [question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16685/what-is-the-filtration-described)

Comment: Yeah I think ch 11 in the reference and then here is the [solution](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/exercise_solutions.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

By definition of the $T$-forward measure $P_T$, the process $\Big\{\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)} \mid t\geq 0\Big\}$ is a martingale under the measure $P_T$, without assuming any specific models of the short rate $r_t$. 
That is, this martingale property is model independent.

However, as a good exercise, you can also do the following:

1. Given the CIR interest rate model under the risk-neutral measure $P$, compute the bond prices.
2. Find the Radon-Nykodim derivative of the $T$-forward measure with respect to the risk-neutral measure, that is, $\frac{dP_T}{dP}\big|_t$, for $0 \leq t \leq T$.
3. Find the bond price formula or SDE under the $T$-forward measure.
4. Show that the process $\Big\{\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)} \mid t\geq 0\Big\}$ is a martingale under the $T$-forward measure.

Comment: precise.But this needs to be clarified

Answer (score 3):

We assume $\mathbb{Q}$ is forward measure. 
$$\mathbb{E^Q}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}|\mathcal{F}_s\right]=\mathbb{E^P}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}\frac{e^{-\int_{s}^{T}r_u\,du}}{P(s,T)}\,|\,\mathcal{F}_s\right]$$
$$\hspace{5cm}=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}{e^{-\int_{s}^{T}r_u\,du}}\,|\,\mathcal{F}_s\right]$$
$$\hspace{6.9cm}=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[\mathbb{E^P}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}{e^{-\int_{s}^{T}r_u\,du}}\,|\,\mathcal{F}_t\right]|\mathcal{F}_s\right]$$
we have
$$\hspace{0.3cm}\mathbb{E^Q}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}|\mathcal{F}_s\right]=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[{e^{-\int_{s}^{t}r_u\,du}}\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r_u\,du\,}\,\,|\,\mathcal{F}_t\right]|\mathcal{F}_s\right]$$
$$\hspace{1.5cm}=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[{e^{-\int_{s}^{t}r_u\,du}}\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}P(t,T)|\mathcal{F}_s\right]$$

$$=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[{e^{-\int_{s}^{t}r_u\,du}}P(t,S)|\mathcal{F}_s\right]$$
then
$$\mathbb{E^Q}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}|\mathcal{F}_s\right]=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}{e^{\int_{0}^{s}r_u\,du}}\,\,\mathbb{E^P}\left[{e^{-\int_{0}^{t}r_u\,du}}P(t,S)|\mathcal{F}_s\right]$$
we know the discounted bond price process $\{e^{-\int_{0}^{t}r_u\,du}P(t,S)\}$ is a martingale under $\mathbb{P}$, thus we have
$$\hspace{1cm}\mathbb{E^Q}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}|\mathcal{F}_s\right]=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}{e^{\int_{0}^{s}r_u\,du}}{e^{-\int_{0}^{s}r_u\,du}}P(s,S)$$
$$=\frac{P(s,S)}{P(s,T)}$$

$$$$
EDIT: Alternatively,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E^Q}\left[\frac{P(t,S)}{P(t,T)}\mid \mathcal{F}_s\right] &= \frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[{e^{-\int_{s}^{t}r_u\,du}}P(t,S)\mid\mathcal{F}_s\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[{e^{-\int_{s}^{t}r_u\,du}}\mathbb{E^P}\Big(e^{-\int_t^Sr_u\,du} \mid \mathcal{F}_t \Big)\mid\mathcal{F}_s\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[\mathbb{E^P}\Big(e^{-\int_s^Sr_u\,du} \mid \mathcal{F}_t \Big)\mid\mathcal{F}_s\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{P(s,T)}\mathbb{E^P}\left[e^{-\int_s^Sr_u\,du}\mid\mathcal{F}_s\right]\\
&= \frac{P(s,S)}{P(s,T)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Please check the typos.

Comment: Hi Gordon , I check my solution, I can not see typos unfortunately. please edit it.

Comment: In most of places, $\mathcal{F}_t$ should be $\mathcal{F}_s$, for $0\leq s \leq t \leq S<T$.

Comment: You do not really need the fact that $\big\{e^{-\int_{0}^{t}r_u\,du}P(t,S) \mid 0 \leq t \leq S\big\}$ is a martingale under $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: I think, this issue is discussed in the Bjork's book

Comment: I added it to your answer.

Comment: It is Completed